# addPersistentStoreWithType method strange compiler error

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, xcode6-beta6

With Xcode 6 beta 6 I got the following compiler error, at this line:

```
persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options:  [:], error: nil)
```

for argument: `NSSQLiteStoreType`

*'NSString' is not identical to 'String'*

The `addPersistentStoreWithType` method require `String`, but predefined values have `NSString` type.

What can I do?

[image][image]

## UPDATE

I tryied now with this, still the same.

```
import Foundation

persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType((NSSQLiteStoreType as String), configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options:nil , error: nil)
```

And now the linker error looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you import Foundation in order to bridge from String to NSString?

Comment: In your original code you had `options:  []` which is wrong, because `[]` is an array, not a dictionary. In your updated code you have `options: nil` which should work, and actually that code compiles in my project. - Those strange linker errors are often resolved by cleaning all derived data once (opt-shift-cmd-K).

Comment: I have cleaned data, does not help

Comment: Do you still get "'NSString' is not identical to 'String'" or just the linker error? - Have your tried to delete all derived data in the Projects tab of Window -> Organizer ?

Comment: delete all derived data in the Projects tab of Window -> Organizer worked, thanks :)